# How can I choose specific products by id on owl-carousel?

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, home-page

I'm trying to add some specific products (choose by product_id, for example) on my homepage using the owl-carousel and a cms block. I did it for categories using the `category_id` filter, but it doesn't work for `product_id`.

How can I make this carousel for a list of chosen `product_ids` (some filter like: products with id 1234, 2142 and 1235) ?

The default version for the owl-carousel and the block:

```
<div id="carousel_featured" class="owl-top-narrow">
    {{block type="filterproducts/latest_home_list" category_id="5" template="filterproducts/list.phtml"}}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($){
    $("#carousel_featured .filter-products .owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        lazyLoad: true,
        itemsCustom: [ [0, 1], [320, 1], [480, 2],[640, 3], [768, 4], [992, 6] ],
        responsiveRefreshRate: 50,
        slideSpeed: 200,
        paginationSpeed: 500,
        scrollPerPage: false,
        stopOnHover: true,
        rewindNav: true,
        rewindSpeed: 600,
        pagination: false,
        navigation: true,
        autoPlay: true,
        navigationText:["<i class='icon-left-open'></i>","<i class='icon-right-open'></i>"]
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: provide content of `filterproducts/list.phtml`

Comment: It's a really big code... with a lot of extentions... but the link is here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5cv8NWLdE2QMGpqYzhTemZ3Ym8

Comment: There is any relation between this product ids that you want to show

Comment: or just create new category with your required products and give that category id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create **new category** from **backend**.

**Add** all your **required products** in that **category**.

**Give that category id to**

```
{{block type="filterproducts/latest_home_list" category_id="<New_Category_Id>" template="filterproducts/list.phtml"}}
```

Comment: How can I sort the products by position? I tried to put `sort_by="position"` but it didn't work...

Comment: use `->addAttributeToSort('position', 'ASC')` with product collection @RafaelMiller